# Why are my brushes see-through in Hammer/CS:GO?

Tags: steam, valve, binary-space-partitioning, source-engine, hammer

I'm making a map for Counter Strike: Global Offensive, but I am having this issue with a part of the map. One of my brushes is weird and see-through in game. [image: broken brushes]
I have no clue what is causing it or how I can fix it. Does anyone know what's going on, and how I could fix it?

Comment: I don't think this is a game development question. My guess is that the guys at gaming.stackexchange.com might know.

Comment: @Superdoggy it's map making (level design), so I would guess it has it place here... The other place would probably be on the the valve technical support...

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt It looks more like a bug report of a Valve FPS game, how does debugging a game engine from a single picture have to do with game development? I'd compare it to a question like "I found a glitch with unity3D, here's a picture, can you fix it?" Anyway, I agree with you though on the technical support point, that probably would be where this fits best.

Comment: What's the texture you're using? Certain textures have holes in them, or are designed to be see-through (such as windows).

Comment: What are the brush's dimensions in Hammer?

Comment: @Superdoggy The question is ontopic. Hammer is the official mapping tool for Source, so it's part of the development process for games based on the Source engine. IOW if you started working on a game based on Source, you'd most likely design the levels as well as events & related scripts in it.

Comment: That being said, it could use an edit to include w/e settings OP is using in Hammer and w/e else. A screenshot isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because those are 'dentils' (an architecture element.  As such, they are spaced apart.  They're supposed to go under a ledge.  Google images of dentils.  Oh, also, look at the file name and see if THAT is named 'dentil'.  That'll tell you.

As a workaround I'd put a background behind it.